# the code about deck.gl : const {data = DATA_URL} = this.props;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deck.gl

Please show me what the `const {data = DATA_URL} =this.props` means.

What's the difference between `const {data = DATA_URL} =this.props` and `const {data} =this.props`?

Comment: That syntax is called [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2)

Comment: Basically, if `this.props.data` is `undefined`, the first example will set `data` to the value of `DATA_URL`, `=` is used to set a default value.

Comment: @Titus Right; I misread the code in the question.